# Get parameters from TD of checked TR

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td aaa="111">sdf</td><td bbb="222">sdfsd</td><td ccc="333">trs</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td aaa="342">hjk</td><td bbb="274">sdfsd</td><td ccc="337">sdg</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td aaa="432">hgj</td><td bbb="652">sdfsd</td><td ccc="747">dih</td></tr>
</table>

<span id="show">show</span>


$("#show").click(function(){
    var text = [];
    $("#tab").each(
        if($(this).find(input[type=checkbox].is(:checked))){
           text.push({
              'aaa': $(this).attr('aaa'),
              'bbb': $(this).attr('bbb'),
               'ccc': $(this).attr('ccc')
          });
        }
    )
        console.log(text);
})
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/KFbbZ/

If i click **show** i would like get all parameters form checked TR. How can i make it? My example is bad...

Comment: You could at least provide an example that is syntactically correct.

Comment: What do you mean you would like to get all the parameters from checked TR?  You want to determine which ones are checked?  Or you want to parse the html/text within the `tr` tag that encompasses the checked checkboxes?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var text, $tr, $td, isChecked;
$("#show").click(function(){
    text = [];
    $("#tab input:checked").each(function(){
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        $tds = $tr.find('td');
        text.push({
           'aaa': $tds.eq(1).attr('aaa'),
           'bbb': $tds.eq(2).attr('bbb'),
            'ccc': $tds.eq(3).attr('ccc')
        });
     });
     console.log(text);
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KFbbZ/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through instances of tables with ID `"tab"` when really you want to be looping through all checked boxes:

```
var $boxes = $('table#tab').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
$boxes.each(function() {
    text.push({
        'aaa': $(this).attr('aaa'),
        'bbb': $(this).attr('bbb'),
        'ccc': $(this).attr('ccc')
    });
});
```

Comment: He needs to loop through all sibling `td` elements to get all the attributes of each, not each `input`... at least that's how I read it.